# Splitting string only it meets requirements in C#

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm trying to split a song title into two strings- the artist and song.
I receive the original string like this: "artist - song".
Using this code, I split the string using '-' as the spliiter:

```
    char[] splitter = { '-' };
    string[] songInfo = new string[2];
    songInfo = winAmp.Split(splitter);
```

This works fine and all, except when I get to a band with '-' in the name, like SR-71.
However, since the original strings are separated with a space then a - and a space again (like SR-71 - Tomorrow), how would I split the string so this happens? I tried changing splitter to a string and inputting

```
        string[] splitter = { " - " };
```

in it, but it returns that there is no overload match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, `string.Split` has no overload that only takes a string array.

You need to call [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx):

```
string[] songInfo = winAmp.Split(new string[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Don't ask me why.

Comment: Can also shorten slightly using implicitly-typed array:
new [] { " - " }

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
 Match M = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.match(str,"(.*?)\s-\s(.*)");
 string Group = M.Groups[1].Value;
 string Song = M.Groups[2].Value;
```